# Mysql query inside a php loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cycle

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (id, rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES ('NULL', '$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')");
```

i need to put it inside a php loop like

```
$c=count($services);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (id, rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES ('NULL', '$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')");
};
```

The problem is that it only inserts into the db the first value of the array and not every value.

The $services_global array looks like this but it could change since it comes from some dynamically generated inputs(into the main page you can add as many services as you wish).

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [service] => Hostess [amount] => 1 [unit_price] => Eu 120,00 [service_price] => Eu 120,00 [service_vat] => 21 ) [1] => Array ( [service] => Pullman [amount] => 4 [unit_price] => Eu 122,00 [service_price] => Eu 488,00 [service_vat] => 21 ) [2] => Array ( [service] => Cena [amount] => 100 [unit_price] => Eu 100,00 [service_price] => Eu 10.000,00 [service_vat] => 10 ))
```

Comment: Is `id` a primary key or has any other constraint?

Comment: What does the `$services_global` array look like? Also, mysql_* functions will soon be deprecated. Please look into using mysqli_* functions or the PDO MySQL library.

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach()` instead of `for()`

Comment: Are you sure you want `NULL` between single quotes, `'NULL'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem here is that `id` is your auto-incrementing primary key, and you are trying to assign the static string `'NULL'` to it on every iteration.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (id, rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES (NULL, '$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')");
```

...or better yet, remove `id` query all together:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES ('$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')");
```

Also, you would be better using a `foreach` loop for this (**EDITED** to help you debug the problem):

```
foreach ($services_global as $service) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO fatture_servizi
              (rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) 
            VALUES
              ('$invoice_rif', '{$service['service']}', '{$service['amount']}', '{$service['unit_price']}', '{$service['service_price']}', '{$service['service_vat']}')";
  echo "Attempting query: $query\n";
  if (!mysql_query($query)) echo "MySQL Error: ".mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: I tried removing the id(that is the primary key) but it keeps adding to the database only the first value of the array.(in the above case `$services_global[0]`)

Comment: @g0dl3ss Try with my edited code above which should hopefully tell you why the query is failing.

Comment: This helped a lot thanks(the problem was that i did set rif_fattura as a unique key while it should not be unique since every row of the query loop has the has the same value for that variable.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier to use a foreach:

```
foreach($services as $row){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (id, rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES (NULL, '$invoice_rif', '{$row['service']}', '{$row['amount']}', '{$row['unit_price']}', '{$row['service_price']}', '{$row['service_vat']}')");
}
```

I hope this will fix your problem!

Comment: Are you sure you want `NULL` between single quotes, `'NULL'`?

Comment: @Konerak Sorry, I didn't look at that part. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using $services_global in the VALUES() and using count($services)... Are they the same? This could be your error...

Also note, a good strategy for looping (its called a loop, not a cycle), you can use FOREACH...

```
foreach($services_global as $service){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (id, rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES ('NULL', '$invoice_rif', '{$service['service']}', '{$service['amount']}', '{$service['unit_price']}', '{$service['service_price']}', '{$service['service_vat']}')");
};
```

I hope thats it!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess that `id` is your primary key and you are trying to insert all your records with the same `id = 'NULL'`.
Usually primary key is integer so it is strange that you don't get the exception instead of data insertion.
Most common solution is to have integer auto incremental primary key, then you don't have to worry about inserting it:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `fatture_servizi` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  /* other columns */
);
```

PHP:

```
$c=count($services);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fatture_servizi 
(rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) 
VALUES 
('$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')";
    mysql_query($sql);
};
```

Besides, `INSERT` is rather heavy operation. If it is possible, I'd use bulk inserts:

```
$c=count($services);
$rows = array();
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $rows[] = "('$invoice_rif', '{$services_global[$i]['service']}', '{$services_global[$i]['amount']}', '{$services_global[$i]['unit_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_price']}', '{$services_global[$i]['service_vat']}')";
}
if(!empty($rows)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fatture_servizi (rif_fattura, servizio, quantita, prezzo_unitario, prezzo_servizio, iva) VALUES " . implode(',', $rows) . ";";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

And don't forget about escaping the data you pass to the database!

Comment: Yep id is auto incrementing, i removed the id value from the query but still only 1 row gets to the db.

Comment: Dump the resulting query to the variable and look at it. And escape the special characters from your input.